# Trouble Simplifying Logarithmic Expressions

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I would appreciate it if someone let me know when it's appropriate to give logarithmic expressions a common denominator. For example, when finding the derivative of $f(x)= x^{\log_2 x}$ using logarithmic differentiation, before multiplying by y, I have $\frac{\ln x}{x \ln 2}$ + $\frac{\log_2 x}{x}$. At this point, my book simplifies by giving both expressions a common denominator of $x ln 2$ and ends up with $f'(x)= \frac{2 \ln x}{x \ln 2}$*$x^{\log_2 x}$ ($x^{\log_2 x}$ was the $y$).

The second example is $f(x)= 2^x*\log_3 7^{x^2-4}$. Not applying logarithmic differentiation, the derivative is $f'(x)= (2^x\ln2)(\log_3 7^{x^2-4}) + \frac{(2x) \ln7}{\ln 3}*2^x$. Why wasn't it necessary to give both expressions a common denominator? I just find it confusing knowing what to do when it comes to simplifying logarithmic expressions. Thanks for any answers!

Comment: Unless this is for a class (in which case, ask your teacher), I would not bother rewriting the derivative expressions except when checking your answer. There is no simplified version of the answer, only versions that for some uses will be more convenient for certain applications than other versions. Don't worry about rewriting the expressions until you have to use them for something else, such as taking a 2nd derivative, setting the 1st derivative equal to zero, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your insight!  This is for a class so I will just get my teacher's opinion on it.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can often get a lot of practice with algebra in trying to match your answer with the book's answer, but as I said before, now is not really the time to worry about what final form is best. For example, ordinarily one considers $\frac{2}{3}$ to be better than $\frac{6}{9},$ but it isn't if you're adding this number to $\frac{2}{9}.$ When you see partial fractions applied to integration, you'll see that breaking up a "combined algebraic fraction" can be more useful sometimes than the combined single-denominator form.